# Mysql REGEXP query `greedy|non-greedy` and match substring between xml element?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, mariadb

I need to use REGEXP to `somefield LIKE '%car%'` but values are in a xmldoc text memo field.

```
<somefield>abc</somefield>
<title>this is a car we need</title>
<xxfield>may_have_CARnival_substr</xxfield>
<desc>There Goes Carnival Description</desc>
..etc...
```

I was able to compile this kind of query but am not sure about the `?` identifier. Do this regexp match inside the `<title>...<` block and not expanding over the ending `<` delimiter per starting field? I need to list 1..n similar fields in a sql query.

```
Select cal.* From calendar cal 
Where cal.group_id IN (11,24,35) 
AND (cal.starttime_utc between '2017-01-01 00:00:00' and '2021-12-31 23:59:59')
AND (cal.args LIKE '%car%')
AND ( LOWER(cal.args) REGEXP '<title>.*?(car).*?<' 
   OR LOWER(cal.args) REGEXP '<desc>.*?(car).*?<'
   OR LOWER(cal.args) REGEXP '<type>.*?(car).*?<' 
   OR LOWER(cal.args) REGEXP '<typetitle>.*?(car).*?<' 
   OR LOWER(cal.args) REGEXP '<typedesc>.*?(car).*?<'
)
Order By cal.starttime_utc DESC, cal.item_id LIMIT 0,150
```

Comment: `.` does not match line break chars and if you have a single tag per line, this will work. Else, exclude `<` from `.*?` and use `[^<]*`.

Comment: What is the reason to use 5 separate regexs? `'<(type)?(title|desc)?> ..' ` - I doubt that there exists `'<>'` in your document. And use explicit collation specifying instead of LOWER usage.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to edit different use-cases by hand to find possible false-positive corner cases. Yes I have a single tag per REGEXP line, similar to a usual `title LIKE %car%` wildcard query syntax.

@Akina I must use case-insensitive match, keyword is any "random" user input values. Do you mean I used an explicit collation per `cal.args` field in this query formula?

Comment: @Akina Five different REGEXP lines is just my skills. You have an example where you list all appropriate xml tag names in a single REGEXP expression. I try that one if it works (I am not a regexp professional). This memo field does not have `<>` chars in a real "internal" data as it's following the xml escaping syntax.

Comment: *Do you mean I used an explicit collation per cal.args field in this query formula?* Yes. `WHERE .. cal.args COLLATE needed_collation REGEXP ..`.

Comment: This will _not_ scale well.  Reconsider the use of `XML`.